# Programmatically accessing camel property from camel context

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

The project I am working at the moment uses camel as the routing framework.
When configuring camel context in spring we pass a property file that contains a bunch of global properties needed when configuring camel routes or for controlling run time behavior:

```
<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="my-id">
    <camel:propertyPlaceholder location="my-system.properties" id="global-properties"/>
    ...
</camel:camelContext>
```

and say my-system.properties has an entry like below:

```
my-system.properties
# Global properties that control my-system configuration and run time
...
foo={{bar}} 
...
```

When configuring the routes I can access `foo` property using the `{{foo}}` notation. It is also available to other beans using `@PropertyInject` annotation. However there is one use case in my design when a plain POJO not created by spring (an enum instead but this is not relevant) needs to access my `foo` property. Because this POJO it is passed the CamelContext as a method argument I find it natural to think I should be able to get the value of `foo` from there. However I spent a bit of time and could not figure out by myself how.

I know I can load the properties file again or even get the system property `System.getProperty("bar")` and everything will work but it looks like cheating to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an api on CamelContext to resolve property placeholders - its the `resolvePropertyPlaceholders` method:

- http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#resolvePropertyPlaceholders(java.lang.String)

Comment: That was the first thing I tried myself before posting this. But I read the documentation wrong. Rather than invoking context `resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{foo}}")` I was calling `resolvePropertyPlaceholders("foo")` and got back the "foo" string. Your answer made me open my eyes larger and got it right. I refused to believe such a basic thing would have been missed from this great framework.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If your POJO is not being managed by the SpringContext I don't see any way you can automatically inject the property. Although your approach may not seem the most fancy or elegant, it has the advantage of not giving you any overhead you could have by using another injection tool.

Comment: I don't want to have it injected as I know this is hard. I just want to get it programmatically from camel context that is available to me.